# How to Play Multiple Audio's in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to play multiple audio files in my React Native application. Currently, it is one audio at a time and i also want single audio to be played at a time. What I want is if one audio is playing and suddenly the user tapped on the second audio button the first one will get paused and second should play. And when the user tapped the first again the paused audio will start again from where it is paused. Similar to whatsapp Audio Messages.

I am using **react-native-audio-recorder-player** for recording and playing audio in my application.
[check app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Bh1.png)

My FlatList Item Design:

{ { this.toggleMediaPlayer(item.audiourl, index) } }}>

```
                                            <TouchableOpacity
                                                style={styles.viewBarWrapper}
                                                onPress={this.onStatusPress}
                                            >
                                                <View style={styles.viewBar}>
                                                    <View style={styles.viewBarPlay} />
                                                </View>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                            <Text style={styles.txtCounter}>
                                                {/* {this.state.playTime} / {this.state.duration} */}
                                            </Text>

                                        </View>
```

**MediaPlayer Function:**

> `toggleMediaPlayer(mediaPath, index) {

```
    if (this.state.mediaFlag[index] == false) {
        this.onStartPlay(mediaPath, index)

        this.state.mediaFlag[index] = true;
        var cloneObj = Object.assign({}, this.state.mediaFlag);
        this.setState({ mediaFlag: cloneObj });
        console.log(this.state.mediaFlag)

    }
    else {
        this.onPausePlay(mediaPath)
        this.state.mediaFlag[index] = false;
        var cloneObj = Object.assign({}, this.state.mediaFlag);
        this.setState({ mediaFlag: cloneObj });
        console.log(this.state.mediaFlag)
    }
}
```

`

**REST CODE**

> audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();

```
async onStartPlay(path, index) {
    console.log('onStartPlay');
    this.audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
    const msg = await this.audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer(path);
    console.log(msg);
    this.audioRecorderPlayer.addPlayBackListener(async (e) => {
        if (e.current_position === e.duration) {
            console.log('finished');
            // await this.setState({ mediaFlag: !this.state.mediaFlag });

            this.state.mediaFlag[index] = false;
            var cloneObj = Object.assign({}, this.state.mediaFlag);
            this.setState({ mediaFlag: cloneObj });
            console.log(this.state.mediaFlag)

            this.audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
            this.audioRecorderPlayer.removePlayBackListener();
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                currentPositionSec: e.current_position,
                currentDurationSec: e.duration,
                playTime: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.current_position)),
                duration: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.duration)),
            })
        }
        return;
    });
};

onPausePlay = async () => {
    await this.audioRecorderPlayer.pausePlayer();
};

async onStopPlay(index) {
    console.log('onStopPlay');
    this.audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
    this.audioRecorderPlayer.removePlayBackListener();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `v2.4.3`, it is not a feature of **react-native-audio-recorder-player** (see https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-audio-recorder-player/issues/130)

But i had to do it myself so here's how i managed to do it:

- The main point is to have a parent component of all players (or a store - like redux or react context) which knows the state of the players (is a player reading its sound? which one?)
- Then, when a player plays a sound, it calls the parent component and the parent component will stop any other player currently reading - it has to be done in a certain order to avoid odd behaviour

Here's my code simplified:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [playerRecording, setPlayerRecording] = useState(false); // Which recording is currently playing?

  const onPlay = async (onStartPlay, playerId) => {
    // No player are reading or it is the same player
    if (!playerRecording || playerRecording === playerId) 
      return onStartPlay();

    // Another player is reading - stop it before starting the new one
    audioRecorderPlayer.removePlayBackListener();
    await audioRecorderPlayer.resumePlayer();
    await audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
    // Start the new player
    onStartPlay();
  };
}

const PlayerComponent = ({onPlay, setPlayerRecording, playerId}) => {
  const onStartPlay = async () => {
    setPlayerRecording(playerId);
    audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer(path);
    ...
  }

  return (
    <PlayButton onPress={() => onPlay(onStartPlay, playerId)} />
  )
}
```